# How to choose all but one UILabel included in self.view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I refresh user data from a webapp, I want to refresh all the labels that present user data. Unfortunately there is also 1 label that does not need to be updated. It's property `UILabel *noAppointments`.

Here's my attempt, which just results in self.noAppointments having a label of Error:

```
for(UILabel *subview in self.view.subviews){
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] && (subview != self.noAppointments)){
        subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        subview.text = [[UserObject userUnique] getStringLabel:subview.tag];
        [subview setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:SYSTEM_FONT_TYPE size:SYSTEM_FONT_SIZE*1]];
        [subview setTextColor:[UIColor LBlueColor]];
    }
}
```

I have also tried this version of testing for inequality of the views:

```
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] && !(subview == self.noAppointments))
```

This also gives an error. The error comes from executing this function

`subview.text = [[UserObject userUnique] getStringLabel:subview.tag];`

on `self.noAppointments`.

I also tried this condition

```
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] && !([subview isEqual:self.noAppointments]))
```

This also failed to exclude `self.noAppointments`. I could give it a dummy tag and the function could then return the right value for this unwanted `UILabel`, but I don't like the idea of modifying a function in another class just to solve this problem. How can I properly reject this class/properly reject equality?

Comment: Your for loop should have worked. What exactly is wrong with that code? Are you saying that noAppointments has text of "Error"?

Comment: Why can't you just add all the labels except for `self.noAppointments` to an array when they are created and just loop through that instead?

Comment: @rdelmar That's what I thought but yes, the UILabel has text of "Error", which I am guessing is somehow returned from the function getStringLabel: because the label self.noAppointments has no tag.

Comment: All views have a tag of 0 by default, so getStringLabel: should work ok for all the views. You should post the whole code from that method. I don't see how a label could display the word "Error" unless you set it to that somewhere.

Comment: @rdelmar But isn't the point that something is wrong with the equality operator or otherwise my method shouldn't be called for self.noAppointments in any case?

Comment: When I test this code, the equality test works fine, so I don't know what your problem is.